# What is the probability of a card of heart or non jack drawn from a standard deck?

Tags: probability

According to the formula UNION of $2$ Events: $$P(E\cup F)=P(E)+P(F)−P(E\cap F)
 - P(\text{heart}) = \frac{13}{52}, P(\text{non-jack}) = \frac{48}{52}, P(\text{heart} \cap \text{non-jack})= \frac{12}{52}\\ \implies P(\text{heart} \cup \text{non-jack}) = \frac{49}{52}.$$ 
But this result does not make sense. I think the answer must be $48$, because there is none of any of the $4$ jacks drawn.
So I would like to know your own idea about this, please? Thank you all!

Comment: So the allowed cards are all the hearts, and all non-jacks? That is, all the cards which are not jacks, and the jack of hearts? Because those are indeed 49 card.s

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at the problem this way: 
We either draw a jack or not a jack. The probability of not drawing a jack is $\frac{48}{52}$.
If we do draw a jack, we are interested in the case that it is the jack of hearts. So the probability of drawing a jack and it being the jack of hearts is 
$\frac{1}{4} \frac{4}{52}=\frac{1}{52}$. Now since the events jack and not-a-jack are disjoint we can simply add the probabilities to find the desired probability.

In your terminology: take E=draw a jack and F=Draw a non-jack which is the jack of hearts. Clearly $P(E\cap F)=0$.

Comment: Thanks Jan! But the probability of drawing a jack 48/52  is a mistake, should be 4/52.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, it should say of not drawing a jack. My apologies I will edit it.

Answer (score 0):

I think my problem is about word. "a heart OR a non jack" means that jack of heart is included as a probability. So 49/52 is the right number.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.